# How do I concatenate outputs of two different models if the shapes are completely different?

Tags: machine-learning, deep-learning, pytorch, computer-vision, lstm

I am having two pretrained models in pytorch which use different type of input data. Both of them I am using for feature extraction and want to concatenate their outputs at the end and put them into LSTM.

I am having the following outputs:

ModelA `[batch size, num of features, num of frames]`

ModelB `[batch size, num of features, num of frames, height, width]`

How can I concatenate them so that I can put concatenated vector into LSTM and train it. I am not sure how to do it in a way so that my concatenated vector still "makes sense" and does not lose any information.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can reshape the second model's output vector such that the new number of features would be `num of features x height x width`

Assuming that both vectors have the same batch size and the same number of frames:
First, you reorder both output vectors such that the order is `[batch size, num of frames, num of features, ...]`

Then, you concatenate on the last dimension:

```
output1 = torch.randn(10, 5, 20)
output2 = torch.randn(10, 7, 20, 100, 200)
output1 = output1.permute(0, 2, 1) 
output2 = output2.permute(0, 2, 1, 3, 4)
output = torch.concatenate([output1, output2], dim=2)
```

Now, the output tensor has all features from both output vectors together, per frame number per instance in batch which would generally make sense

Answer (score 1):

@Yakov Dan answer is correct, here is another approach:

- Reshape the outputs of `ModelA` and `ModelB` to have the same number of frames,

> ModelA  shape [batch size, num of features, num of frames] and
> ModelB has the shape [batch size, num of features, num of frames, height, width].

- Reshape ModelB to have the same number of frames as ModelA.
- Flatten the outputs of ModelA and ModelB along the height and width dimensions. This will convert the outputs from 5-dimensional tensors to 3-dimensional tensors, where each frame is represented as a single vector.
- Concatenate the flattened outputs of ModelA and ModelB along the feature dimension. This will result in a tensor with the shape `[batch size, num of features_A + num of features_B, num of frames]`.

```py
output_modelA = torch.randn(batch_size, num_features_A, num_frames)
output_modelB = torch.randn(batch_size, num_features_B, num_frames, height, width)

# Reshape ModelB to have the same number of frames as ModelA
output_modelB = output_modelB.view(batch_size, num_features_B, num_frames, -1)

# Flatten the outputs of ModelA and ModelB
output_modelA = output_modelA.view(batch_size, num_features_A, -1)
output_modelB = output_modelB.view(batch_size, num_features_B, -1)

# Concatenate the flattened outputs along the feature dimension
concatenated_output = torch.cat((output_modelA, output_modelB), dim=1)

# Define the LSTM module

# Pass the concatenated tensor into the LSTM
```